# Issue getting insights from FQL api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am interested in returning back a few metrics from insights but i am having difficulty getting results from FQL.

I need to get back the following.
page impressions/likes/shares
posts impressions/likes/share/comments

For post impressions

```
fql?q=SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=#### AND metric='post_impressions_unique' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-10-30') AND period=period('lifetime')
```

For page impressions

```
fql?q=SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=#### AND metric='page_impressions' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-10-30') AND period=period('lifetime')
```

i get back empty data sets:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: please let me know if i can provide further information to help diagnose this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at first. According to the documentation, 'page_impressions' and 'page_impressions_unique' can only take the periods of 'day', 'week', and 'days_28'. If that doesn't fix the problem, try changing to a different end date (which was my problem).

Comment: How was the date the issue? What did you have to change it to for the period you were looking for?